# which has followed oil prices lower

Tags: phrase-meaning

> The misfortunes of oil have been hard on the Canadian currency,
>   **which has followed oil prices lower**. Canada's economy is dependent on oil and economists believe falling prices will slow 2015
>   growth.*(Canadian dollar plunges to 5-year low as oil dips below $60 -
>   CBC news Dec. 11 2014)*

Does the bold part mean "which came after oil prices lower"?
If so, why "oil prices lower" instead of "lower oil prices"?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it *is* poorly worded.

I would take it to mean that *both* are worth less at the *same* time. A better way to word it would be this:

> The misfortunes of oil have been hard on the Canadian currency, which has lowered in value similarly to oil prices.